# Unable to bring back images, they are listed in my scene collection, but when I turn the eye back on they don't show up,, even when I frame selected?

Tags: scene, collections

I am working on modeling fundamentals and have made several items, turned eye off as I finish and move on tot the next item.  But when I turn the eye back on to the items I created they do not show up., even when I click frame selected.  what am I doing wrong?  I'm still fairly knew at this...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Also please note that vernacular/imprecise terms like "eye" are not helpful to those who want to help you.  Perhaps hover over the eye and some help text will tell you the actual name of the button.  Best wishes to you.